# Cellular Homology computation example in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $M_g$ be the closed orientable surface of genus $g$ with its usual $CW$ structure consisting of one $0$-cell, $2g$ $1$-cells, and one $2$-cell attached by the product of the commutators $[a_1,b_1] \dots [a_g, b_g]$. The associated cellular chain complex is $$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \overset{d_2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^{2g} \overset{d_1}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

In the example it is simply stated that $d_2$ is $0$ because each $a_i$ or $b_i$ appears with its inverse in the product of the commutators and so the $\Delta_{\alpha \beta}$ are homotopic to constant maps.

Ok. This seems like a very hand-wavy explanation and not applicable to more general situations.

How do I compute the degree of $\Delta_{\alpha \beta}: \partial D_n^{\alpha} \to S_{\beta}^{n-1}$? Is there a computation to this. I have seen solution that this can be done using matrices but I cannot actually find an explanation calculating degrees using matrices.

Anyway, I am very lost on how to compute degree and Hatcher's explanation are a bit too heuristic for me at the moment.

The matrix computation I am mentioning looks something like this.

http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/f03/algtop/opg/S2.2.pdf

I would really appreciate an explanation :)

(No need to go through the example in the link, a very simple situation as that for the Torus would suffice)

Comment: I think in this particular example you assume a "nice" construction on the CW complex by which I mean when you look at the composition $S^1_{\alpha} \to X^1 \to S^1_{\beta}$ you are either going clockwise or counterclockwise. These produce degrees of 1 or -1. This might be hand wavy to you still, but I believe this is the intuition. I think the moral is that the CW structure is chosen to be "convenient."

Comment: are you still interested in a step by step solution of this? I may provide one if you are still looking for one.